# How can I change the end of a line depending on what is in next line?

Tags: sed, awk

I have a file full of text like:

```
CREATE TABLE `wild_adventure_game` (
  `game_instance_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `free_game_config_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `respin_instance_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `stake` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `pay_line_win` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `bonus_win` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `total_win` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Sometimes there is a comma at the end of the line that contains `ENGINE`, sometimes not. I want to replace (ie delete) that comma - my first, naive attempt was something like:

```
sed -e 's/'$) ENGINE/$) ENGINE/' < the_file
```

This didn't work, of course, but is it possible to wrangle `sed` in such a way that it can be done? Or if not, perhaps `awk`? In the worst case I can write a bash script, but that will be rather klunky.

***Edit***

I see I made a typo above - it should have been:

```
sed -e 's/,$) ENGINE/$) ENGINE/' < the_file
```

So, in the example, I want to replace the comma at the end of the next to last line with nothing, or more generally, simply replace some substring at the end of the last line before a line that matches some expression. In my failed attempt with `sed`, I use `$` to represent the end of a line, and I sort of already knew that it couldn't work, because sed reads lines one by one, not across line endings; but it illustrates what I'd like to achieve - and it may not be possible with `sed`.

Comment: The title says "change […] line depending on […] next line". Then the body is about "comma at the end of the line that contains `ENGINE`", no relation to the previous or the next line. Then your `sed` command is kinda like you did want to do something to the previous line; but it doesn't include a comma (it's improperly quoted instead, I think). Very unclear. The question contains example input. Please [edit] and post the desired *output* as well.

Comment: IMO instead of "(incorrect content). Sorry, typo, it should have been … (erratum)" you should just change the incorrect content and make it correct. In case anyone wants to know what has been corrected, there's the [revision history](https://superuser.com/posts/1568906/revisions). Reading an unclear post which corrects itself at the end is a waste of time. The post should be clear from its very beginning.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
sed '/ENGINE/ s/,$//' file
```

For any line that *contains* "ENGINE", delete a comma at end of line.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer in my question - see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

## An awk solution

```
  /^) ENGINE/ {
    sub( /,$/, "" )
    print
    next
  }

  {
    print
  }
```